# Android don't package resource with apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have an image in my project that I use only for aesthetic purposes in a `tools` attribute of an xml file.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:src="@drawable/dummy_pic" />
```

Is there a way I can tell Android Studio to never package `dummy_pic` when building an apk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a new feature of the [gradle build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking).

Example:

```
android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Or implement your own gradle task.

Comment: Specifically use proguard with `shrinkResources true` as your link suggests. Also, I would hope it is smart enough to mark images only used with `tools` attribute as unused.

Comment: Yes, a new gradle feature is based on ProGuard, but by default ProGuard optimizes only bytecode.

Comment: The only way for sure is to test it with huge image size.